# K8s Network policy endPort can not be applied

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I'm trying to apply egress port range for my k8s network policy like this:

```
 egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 32000
      endPort: 32768
```

Starting fine but when I describe that, I only see that port `32000` is allowed.
Do I miss something? Or have I made some mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you took this example from  [Targeting a range of Ports](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#targeting-a-range-of-ports). Here are 2 questions:

1. I see `endPort` works only with `NetworkPolicyEndPort` enabled feature. Despite the fact it is states, this feature enabled by default, can you please
   check if it turned for you?
   [image]
2. Whats your CNI plugin and does it support `endPort` in NetworkPolicy spec?

[image]

Comment: thanks @WytrzymałyWiktor look like i need to enabled feature gate in api-sever